# Core Data (Magical Record) + WatchKit Extension + Cocoa Touch Framework

Tags: swift, core-data, watchkit, magicalrecord, cocoa-touch

Here's what I'm up to:

**I now have**

- An iPhone app
- A WatchKit Extension
- A Cocoa Touch Framework that holds all my shared classes

**What I would like to accomplish**, is having a persistent storage (Core Data) that is shared between my iPhone app and WatchKit Extension.

**So this is what I've done so far**

- Create an app group to have a shared container.
- Add a Core Data Model (Model.xcdatamodeld) to my Cocoa Touch Framework.
- Created one Entity in this model
- Created an NSMangedObject subclass for this entity and added is to my Cocoa Touch Framework
- Added a DataManager class to my Cocoa Touch Framework

Here what the initializer in my DataManager looks like

```
public init() {
    let sharedContainerURL: NSURL? = NSFileManager.defaultManager().containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.com.company.Project")
    if let sharedContainerURL = sharedContainerURL {
        let storeURL = sharedContainerURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Model.sqlite")
        MagicalRecord.setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreAtURL(storeURL)
        let station: Station? = Station.MR_createEntity()
    }
}
```

**The issue I'm running into**

When I init my DataManager from the iPhone app's AppDelegate, no crash occures, but `station` will be nil.

When I replace the last line with `let stations: [Station]? = Station.MR_findAll() as? [Station]` the app crashes and shows the following error: `A fetch request must have an entity.`

I've searched all of SO and Magical Records issues on GitHub, but couldn't find anything to push me in the right direction. All help is much appreciated.

Comment: Whatever you implement, take into account that watchOS 2 extensions actually run on the watch itself. Read the Managing your Data section in the transition guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleWatch2TransitionGuide/UpdatetheAppCode.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Leo Natan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/983912/leo-natan)'s comment I now realize that I should store my core data in both my iPhone app's sandbox as well as in my WatchKit app's sandbox. And not inside a shared container, like I was trying to.

When building for Watch OS 2, I'll be able to use the WatchKit Connectivity Framework to keep both databases in sync. In the meanwhile I could use a solution like [MMWormhole](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole) to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I have done my task in my live app with watch and iPhone both. i not needs 2 stores. and `MMWormhole` is good one to help for instant call back both the sides. also i have handled watch's event by `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest.`

The sync is proper and works well.

I have followed this forum. - http://www.makeandbuild.com/blog/post/watchkit-with-shared-core-data

Hope this may help you.